# Is that family of linear transformations $(T_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ Banach spaces e over $\mathbb{K}$ and $T_{n}$ $B(X,Y)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then

given $x \in X$ and $f \in B(Y,\mathbb{K})$, the sequence $f(T_{n}(x))$ is bounded in $\mathbb{K}$ then the sequence $(T_{n})$ is bounded in $B(X,Y)$.

any hint of how can i do this?

Comment: First you want to show that for every $x\in X$ the sequence $T_n(x)$ is bounded in $Y$. Then you want to invoke a famous theorem.

Comment: but how can i prove that?

Comment: First show that weakly bounded sequences are norm-bounded using uniform boundedness together with the isometry into the double dual. Then apply uniform boundedness again to deduce that the $T_n$ are operator-bounded.

Comment: What exactly is $f$? A linear functional on $Y$? Perhaps the statement should read "$f\in B(Y,\mathbb K)$."